# При перетаскивании кнопки теряется фокус

Tags: java, swing, gui

Привет.

Реализовал перетаскивание компонентов, но если убрать курсор за границы JFrame и вернуть назад при резких движениях мыши теряется с кнопки теряется фокус.

Подскажите как сделать так что бы при возвращении курсора в центральную область кнопки фокус не терялся?

[Демонстрация](https://youtu.be/z9TaPhoRqJ4)

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
/**Для корректной работы необходимо создать объект этого класса и
передать его в MouseMotionListener, MouseListener компонента,
а так же ComponentListener в родителя компонента**/
public class MoveElement extends ComponentAdapter implements  MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
private final JComponent root;
private JComponent component;

private Point csl_new;//курсор, новые координаты на экране
private Point csl_old;//курсор, старые координаты на экране
private Point panePoint;//координаты курсора на панели
private Point pointComponent;//координата компонена на панели
private boolean asEnter;
private Rectangle rect;
private Rectangle comRect;
private Rectangle comRectCenter;
private int comX;
private int comY;
private int h;
private int w;

public MoveElement(JComponent component, JComponent root) {
    this.component = component;
    this.root = root;

}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    this.pointComponent = component.getLocation();
    comX = component.getBounds().x;
    comY = component.getBounds().y;
    h = component.getHeight();
    w = component.getWidth();
    mouseLocationPane(e, pointComponent);
    comRectCenter = new Rectangle(comX + w / 3, comY + h / 3, w / 2, h / 2);
    comRect.setLocation(component.getLocation());
    asEnter = rect.contains(comRect);
    csl_old = csl_new;
    csl_new = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    component.setLocation(move(csl_new, csl_old, pointComponent, asEnter));
    component.repaint();
}

//Определение координат курсора на панели
private Point mouseLocationPane(MouseEvent e, Point pointComponent) {
    panePoint = new Point(e.getX() + pointComponent.x, e.getY() + pointComponent.y);
    return panePoint;
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    comX = component.getBounds().x;
    comY = component.getBounds().y;
    h = component.getHeight();
    w = component.getWidth();


    this.pointComponent = component.getLocation();
    comRectCenter = new Rectangle(comX + w / 3, comY + h / 3, w / 2, h / 2);
    System.out.println(comRectCenter);
    csl_new = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    rect = new Rectangle(root.getBounds());
    comRect = new Rectangle(component.getBounds());
    asEnter = rect.contains(e.getPoint());
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    asEnter = false;
    panePoint = null;
    rect = null;
    comRect = null;
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("enter");
    mousePressed(e);
    mouseDragged(e);
    asEnter = true;
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("exit");
    asEnter = false;
}

//Расчет движения объекта и ограничение выхода за пределы формы
private Point move(Point csl_new, Point csl_old, Point pointComponent, boolean asEnter) {
    int cnewX = csl_new.x;
    int cnewY = csl_new.y;
    int coldX = csl_old.x;
    int coldY = csl_old.y;
    int comX = pointComponent.x;
    int comY = pointComponent.y;

    if (!asEnter && comX <= 0) {
        comX = 0;
    } else if (!asEnter && comX + component.getWidth() >= rect.getWidth()) {
        comX = (int) rect.getWidth() - component.getWidth();
    }

    if (!asEnter && comY <= 0) {
        comY = 0;
    } else if (!asEnter && comY + component.getHeight() >= rect.getHeight()) {
        comY = (int) rect.getHeight() - component.getHeight();
    }
    Point point;
    if (comRectCenter.contains(panePoint) || rect.contains(panePoint) && comRect.contains(panePoint)) {
        point = new Point(comX + (cnewX - coldX), comY + (cnewY - coldY));
    } else {
        point = new Point(comX, comY);
    }


    return point;
}

//При уменьшении окна, компонент не выходит за пределы окна
@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    super.componentResized(e);
    rect = new Rectangle(root.getBounds());
    this.pointComponent = component.getLocation();
    comRect = new Rectangle(component.getBounds());
    asEnter = rect.contains(comRect);
    Point pointPane = new Point(root.getWidth(), root.getHeight());
    Point pointCom = new Point(component.getX() + component.getWidth(), component.getY() + component.getHeight());

    if (root.getWidth() - pointCom.getX() <= 0) {
        component.setLocation(root.getWidth() - component.getWidth(), component.getY());
    }

    if (root.getHeight() - pointCom.getY() <= 0) {
        component.setLocation(component.getX(), root.getHeight() - component.getHeight());
    }

    pointPane = null;
    pointCom = null;
    rect = null;
    comRect = null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нашел решение.**

Нужно прямоугольник следящий находится ли курсор в его области, уменьшать если курсор вышел за его пределы и увеличить до размера компонента когда он возвращается в его область.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
* Для корректной работы необходимо создать объект этого класса и
* передать его в MouseMotionListener, MouseListener компонента,
* а так же ComponentAdapter в родителя компонента
**/
public class MoveElement extends ComponentAdapter implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
private final JComponent root;
private JComponent component;

private Point csl_new;//курсор, новые координаты на экране
private Point csl_old;//курсор, старые координаты на экране
private Point panePoint;//координаты курсора на панели
private Point pointComponent;//координата компонена на панели
private boolean asContains;
private boolean asEnter;
private Rectangle rect;
private Rectangle comRect;
private Rectangle comRectCenter;
private int comX;
private int comY;
private int h;
private int w;


public MoveElement(JComponent component, JComponent root) {
    this.component = component;
    this.root = root;
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    this.pointComponent = component.getLocation();
    comX = component.getX();
    comY = component.getY();
    w = component.getWidth();
    h = component.getHeight();
    comRect.setLocation(component.getLocation());
    mouseLocationPane(e, pointComponent);
    sizeRectCenter(comRectCenter, panePoint);
    asContains = rect.contains(comRect);
    csl_old = csl_new;
    csl_new = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    component.setLocation(move(csl_new, csl_old, pointComponent, asContains));
    component.repaint();
}

//Определение координат курсора на панели
private Point mouseLocationPane(MouseEvent e, Point pointComponent) {
    panePoint = new Point(e.getX() + pointComponent.x, e.getY() + pointComponent.y);
    return panePoint;
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}


public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    this.pointComponent = component.getLocation();
    comX = component.getX();
    comY = component.getY();
    w = component.getWidth();
    h = component.getHeight();
    csl_new = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    rect = new Rectangle(root.getBounds());
    comRectCenter = new Rectangle(component.getBounds());
    comRect = new Rectangle(component.getBounds());
    asContains = rect.contains(comRect);
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    asContains = false;
    panePoint = null;
    rect = null;
    comRect = null;
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    asContains = false;
}

//Расчет движения объекта и ограничение выхода за пределы формы
private Point move(Point csl_new, Point csl_old, Point pointComponent, boolean asContains) {
    int cnewX = csl_new.x;
    int cnewY = csl_new.y;
    int coldX = csl_old.x;
    int coldY = csl_old.y;
    int comX = pointComponent.x;
    int comY = pointComponent.y;

    if (!asContains && comX <= 0) {
        comX = 0;
    } else if (!asContains && comX + component.getWidth() >= rect.getWidth()) {
        comX = (int) rect.getWidth() - component.getWidth();
    }

    if (!asContains && comY <= 0) {
        comY = 0;
    } else if (!asContains && comY + component.getHeight() >= rect.getHeight()) {
        comY = (int) rect.getHeight() - component.getHeight();
    }

    Point point;
    if (asEnter) {
        point = new Point(comX + (cnewX - coldX), comY + (cnewY - coldY));
    } else {
        point = new Point(comX, comY);
    }

    return point;
}

//При уменьшении окна, компонент не выходит за пределы окна
@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    super.componentResized(e);
    rect = new Rectangle(root.getBounds());
    this.pointComponent = component.getLocation();
    comRect = new Rectangle(component.getBounds());
    asContains = rect.contains(comRect);
    Point pointPane = new Point(root.getWidth(), root.getHeight());
    Point pointCom = new Point(component.getX() + component.getWidth(), component.getY() + component.getHeight());

    if (root.getWidth() - pointCom.getX() <= 0) {
        component.setLocation(root.getWidth() - component.getWidth(), component.getY());
    }

    if (root.getHeight() - pointCom.getY() <= 0) {
        component.setLocation(component.getX(), root.getHeight() - component.getHeight());
    }

    pointPane = null;
    pointCom = null;
    rect = null;
    comRect = null;
}


private void sizeRectCenter(Rectangle comRectCenter, Point panePoint) {
    if (comRectCenter.contains(panePoint)) {
        comRectCenter.setLocation(comX, comY);
        comRectCenter.setSize(w, h);
        asEnter = true;
    } else {
        comRectCenter.setLocation(comX + w / 2, comY);
        comRectCenter.setSize(1, h);
        asEnter = false;
    }
}
}
```